# how to upload a csv file and update the mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, csv

I want to use a csv file to update the mysql scv table. how to code ? I have no experiece doing this job.

```
<p>please select a scv file to upload</p>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="scv"  />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin');
    mysql_select_db('linjuming');
    // how to upload a scv file and insert or update the "csv" table?

?>
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MYSQL Upload, import .csv file to mysql-process-table design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657204/php-mysql-upload-import-csv-file-to-mysql-process-table-design)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upload file:

```
<form action="upload_target.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Your `upload_target.php`

$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

```
if ($ext == "csv" && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0)
{
    $target = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);

    if (($handle = fopen($target, "r")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) 
        {
            print_r($data);
        }

        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Very basic and with very few checks / validations. The `print_r($data)` contains one line of your csv that you can now insert in your database.

However, I would recommend using PDO or MySQLi for that task, since the mysql functions of PHP will be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There's several parts of this:

First, your form MUST have the enctype set, as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="index.php" method="post">
```

Otherwise, it will not accept file uploads.

Once you've done that, then you can access the file using the [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) variable.  After the file has been uploaded, then you can access it like so:

```
if (isset($_FILES["scv"])) {
    $file = $_FILES["scv"];
    $file_name = $file["name"];
    $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if ($ext!="CSV" && $ext!="TXT") {
        die('The file must be csv or txt format.');
    }
    $saveto_path_and_name = '/path/to/file.csv'; // Where you want to save the file
    move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $saveto_path_and_name);
}
```

Once you've saved the file, you then can open it and import it.  That's not trivial to do, but here's some primer code:

```
// Open the file for reading
$handle = @fopen($saveto_path_and_name, "r") or die(__("Unable to open uploaded file!", "inventory"));
// Grab the first row to do some checks
$row = fgets($inv_file, 4096);
// See if it's comma or tab delimited
if (stripos($inv_row, "\t")) {
    $sep = "\t";
} else {
    $sep = ",";
}

while ( ! feof($handle)) {
    $rowcount = 0;
    // Get the individual fields
    $inv_fields = explode($sep, $inv_row);
    $fields = array();
    // Iterate through the fields to do any sanitization, etc.
    foreach ($inv_fields as $field) {
        // Highly recommended to sanitize the variable $field here....
        $fields[] = $field;
        $rowcount++;
}
    // This is where you would write your query statement to insert the data
    // This is just EXAMPLE code.  Use the DB access of your choice (PDO, MySQLi)
    $sql = vsprintf('INSERT INTO `table` (`column`, `column2`, ...) VALUES (%s, %d, ...)', $fields);
    // Get the next row of data from the file
    $row = fgets($inv_file, 4096);
}
```